# Ember-CLI Routing: Changed my route/template structure, but build does not recognize the changes?

Tags: ember.js, ember-cli

I just now, changed my route structure within ember-cli and broke my app.  I wanted to nest my current structure one level deeper...

**Before:**

```
Router.map(function() {
    this.resource('placements', function() {
        this.route('add');
        this.route('import');
        this.route('open');
    });
    this.route('admin');
});
```

**After:**

```
Router.map(function() {
    this.resource('portal', function() {
        this.resource('placements', function() {
            this.route('add');
            this.route('import');
            this.route('open');
        });
        this.route('admin');
    });
});
```

My Template structure also needed to change...

**Before:**

```
- templates/
-     placements/
-         add.hbs
-         import.hbs
-         index.hbs
-         open.hbs
-     admin.hbs
-     application.hbs
-     index.hbs
-     placements.hbs
```

**After:**

```
- templates/
-     portal/
-         placements/
-             add.hbs
-             import.hbs
-             index.hbs
-             open.hbs
-         admin.hbs
-         index.hbs
-         placements.hbs
-     application.hbs
-     index.hbs
-     portal.hbs
```

I thought I have made all the changes 1-to-1 but for some reason when I relaunched ember server, the nested "placements" routes are broken.

In the **console log**, I noticed that ember is still trying to look for the `placements.index` under the old `templates/placements/index` rather than the new directory.

There is one theory that templates can't be nested in the same way that the router can?  That implies that I might need to explicitly define each route with a **[`renderTemplate` hook](http://emberjs.com/guides/routing/rendering-a-template/)** in order for it to display the correct template... this can be a pain because this project is going to be pretty large... perhaps there is something else that I am doing wrong?

Comment: I'm not sure you need to nest the templates directory. I think Ember doesn't do template resolution more than one level, even if the route is nested more than one level.

Comment: If that is true, then it explains the problem... but then how to define such a nested structure and have ember be able to find the correct templates?

Comment: I think Ember's template resolution always goes templates/resource/route.hbs. Even if the resource in the path is nested under another reason. It's kind of like how when you're transitioning to a route, you would always go `route.transitionTo('placements.add')` instead of `route.transitionTo('portal.placements.add')`, for instance. I think the idea is to reduce the coupling between the app logic and the url structure, so URL's can be changed without needing to completely change the logic in the app.

Comment: @Adam The problem is that `placements.hbs` has an `{{output}}` and inside of that there is an "index" by default, and 3 other pages (add, import, open) that render inside of it... now by bumping the `placements/` directory up, it kills the `placements.hbs` and just renders the `index.hbs` instead... I hope that makes sense

Comment: its possible my understanding of how it works is flawed from the start... however it was working fine when there was just one level deep

Comment: Ok, I figured it out! @Adam is correct, though it did not seem intuitive to me until I played with it more.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

After working on the comments @Adam left me.  I was able to figure out the correct way to work with the templates.

Templates, indeed do not nest in exactly the same pattern that resource/routes do.

**Given the new route structure I made:**

```
Router.map(function() {
    this.resource('portal', function() {
        this.resource('placements', function() {
            this.route('add');
            this.route('import');
            this.route('open');
        });
        this.route('admin');
    });
});
```

**The templates should be structured like so:**

```
- templates/
-     placements/
-         add.hbs
-         import.hbs
-         index.hbs
-         open.hbs
-     portal/
-         admin.hbs
-         index.hbs
-     application.hbs
-     index.hbs
-     placements.hbs
-     portal.hbs
```

When you define a "resource", that essentially causes that particular route to be a top level object, regardless of how deeply nested it appears in the router map.  `placements.hbs` and `portal.hbs` (from above) are "resource" (top level) templates and are placed in the top level of the templates directory accordingly.

Since those two "resource" templates each have an `{{outlet}}` the "children" route templates need to be placed within a top level *directory* which is named after its corresponding resource.

The Ember-CLI docs describe this pattern only showing an example one level deep, so I first assumed that the pattern repeated going in deeper. I hope this helps clarify the actual way to go for anyone else that is learning Ember.

---

### Update:

*As of EMBER 1.7.0*

**Routes are now nestable!**

This is exciting news for me personally, but it merits an update to this answer.

Resources are still usable as the example above, so if you are comfortable with that, you can keep going that way for a while. But keep in mind, Resources are planned for an eventual path to deprecation. Eventually, there will only be routes and nested routes.

The good news is that, if you follow the new pattern, you can nest your templates more naturally to match your router structure, just like a natural REST style app should be. No more awkward mental mapping.

**For instance this same router from above (with the slight change):**

```
Router.map(function() {
    this.route('portal', function() {
        this.route('placements', function() {
            this.route('add');
            this.route('import');
            this.route('open');
        });
        this.route('admin');
    });
});
```

**The templates can be structured like so:**

```
- templates/
-     portal/
-         placements/
-             add.hbs
-             import.hbs
-             index.hbs
-             open.hbs
-         admin.hbs
-         index.hbs
-         placements.hbs
-     application.hbs
-     index.hbs
-     portal.hbs
```

The same pattern applies to nesting the corresponding /routes, /controllers, /adapters, etc., etc.

This also means (with this new pattern) `{{link-to}}` helpers and `transitionTo` methods will need to include the full path of a route:  e.g.  `{{link-to 'portal.placements.index'}}`.

Comment: Grapho thx for your valuable research on this topic. As I'm going to choose which strategy use could you tell where did you read about resource usage deprecation?

Comment: @masciugo i try to keep up with the blog posts on http://emberjs.com/blog/ where they make announcements on development and changes.  I am also on IRC #emberjs and hear a lot there too